# Boolean Table in 2D array C

Tags: c, recursion

I have some dificulties in creating the following array. My task is to fill using recursion a 2D array  with all the possible combinations of 0 and 1  taken m times in lexical order. Mathematically speaking there are 2 ^ m combinations.My program just fills the first 3 rows of the array with the same order 0 1 0 1 and then just prints for the rest of the rows 0 0 0 0.

Example 
m=4

```
0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   
0   0   1   0   
0   0   1   1   
0   1   0   0   
0   1   0   1   
0   1   1   0   
0   1   1   1   
1   0   0   0   
1   0   0   1   
1   0   1   0   
1   0   1   1   
1   1   0   0   
1   1   0   1   
1   1   1   0   
1   1   1   1
```

This is my code so far and I appreciate if someone could correct it and explain me what I am doing wrong as I can't spot the mistake myself

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

void *safeMalloc(int n) {
    void *p = malloc(n);
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("Error: malloc(%d) failed. Out of memory?\n", n);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return p;
}


void combine(int** arrTF,int m,int n,int row,int col){
    if(m==0){
        if(row<pow(2,m)){
            row++;
            combine(arrTF,n,n,row,0);
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }else{
        arrTF[row][col]=0;
        col++;
        combine(arrTF,m-1,n,row,col);

        arrTF[row][col]=1;
        col++;
        combine(arrTF,m-1,n,row,col);
    }

}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int m
    scanf("%d",&m);


    int** arrTF;

    arrTF = safeMalloc(pow(2,m)*sizeof(int *));
    for (int r=0; r < pow(2,m); r++) {
        arrTF[r] = safeMalloc(m*sizeof(int));
    }


    for(int i=0;i<pow(2,m);i++){
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
            arrTF[i][j]=0;
        }
    }

    combine(arrTF,m,m,0,0);

    for(int i=0;i<pow(2,m);i++){
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
            printf("%d ",arrTF[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You use `pow(2, m)` and `m` very interchangeably, and probably mix them up some. Besides that, the right tool to solve problems like this is a *debugger*. I suggest you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger to step through your program line by line while monitoring values of variables.

Comment: I don't think that a debugger will help me because I am pretty sure that my logic is off.Maybe you could explain me how to approach this program from a logical point of view as I now think  that I have a problem with the col variable after exiting the first recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all the possible `(2^m)` combinations of `0's` and `1's` taken `m` times in lexical order and you are using a 2D array to store the result.
Things would be very easy if you just want to print all the possible combination of `0's` and `1's` instead of storing it in 2D array and printing array later.

Storing a combination of `0's` and `1's` to 2D array is a little bit tricky as every combination is one element of your 2D array.
You want to generate the combination of `0's` and `1's` in accordance with the recursive algorithm.
So, let's say, at some stage if your algorithm generates the combination **0010** which is stored in an element in 2D array.
And the next combination would be **0011** which the recursive algorithm will generate just by changing the last number from **0** to **1** in the last combination (**0010**).

So, that means everytime when a combination is generated, you need to copy that combination to its successive location in 2D array.
For e.g. if **0010** is stored at index 2 in 2D array before the algorithm starts computing the next combination, we need to do two things:

1. Copy the elements of index 2 to index 3
2. Increase the row number so that last combination will be intact

(Say, this is 2D array)

**|0|0|0|0|**    *index 0*

**|0|0|0|1|**    *index 1*

**|0|0|1|0|**    *index 2 ---> copy this to its successive location (i.e. at index 3)*

**|0|0|1|1|**    *index 3 ---> Last combination (index 2) and the last digit is changed from 0 to 1*

.....

.....

.....

This we need to do for after every combination generated.
Now, I hope you got where you are making the mistake.

Few practice good to follow:

1. If you want to allocate memory as well as initialized it with 0, use `calloc` instead of `malloc`.
2. Any math function you are calling again and again for the same input, it's better to call it once and store the result in a variable and use that result where ever required.
3. Do not include any header file which is not required in your program.
4. Once done, make sure to free the dynamically allocated memory in your program.

I have made the corrections in your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void *safeMalloc(size_t n, size_t size) {
    void *p = calloc(n, size);
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("Error: calloc(%zu) failed. Out of memory!\n", n);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return p;
}

void deallocate(int ** ptr, int row) {
    for(int i = 0; i<row; i++)
            free(ptr[i]);
    free(ptr);
}

void combine(int **arrTF, int m, int max_col, int max_row) {
    static int row;
    if(m==0){
        int i;
        if (row<(max_row - 1))
        {
            for(i=0; i<max_col; i++)
                arrTF[row+1][i] = arrTF[row][i];
        }
        row++;
        return;
    } else {
        arrTF[row][max_col-m] = 0;
        combine(arrTF, m-1, max_col, max_row);

        arrTF[row][max_col-m] = 1;
        combine(arrTF, m-1, max_col, max_row);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int** arrTF;
    int m, max_row;

    printf ("Enter number: \n");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    max_row = pow(2, m);

    arrTF = safeMalloc(max_row, sizeof(int *));
    for (int r=0; r<max_row; r++) {
        arrTF[r] = safeMalloc(m, sizeof(int));
    }

    combine(arrTF, m, m, max_row);

    for(int i=0; i<max_row; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<m; j++) {
            printf("%d ", arrTF[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    deallocate(arrTF, max_row);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out
Enter number: 
2
0 0 
0 1 
1 0 
1 1 

$ ./a.out
4
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 
0 0 1 0 
0 0 1 1 
0 1 0 0 
0 1 0 1 
0 1 1 0 
0 1 1 1 
1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 1 
1 0 1 0 
1 0 1 1 
1 1 0 0 
1 1 0 1 
1 1 1 0 
1 1 1 1
```

Hope this helps.